# Why does WebForms keep rendering this data- attribute?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

WebForms keeps re-rendering a `TextBox` control with a `data-` attribute in spite of my code removing it on PostBack-- which I shouldn't have to do in the first place, since the PostBack process clears attributes. I've tried clearing the attributes in `OnInit` and `OnUnload`, but they somehow reappear after leaving code-behind. They only **ever** reset through the `TextChanged` event.

I'm going crazy trying to figure out if I have a cache setting somewhere in my web.config that would prevent ASP.NET from properly removing this attribute.

For reference, the (as far as I can determine) relevant sections of my code:

.aspx JavaScript:

```
$("[data-confirm]").each(function () {
    var alertText = $(this).attr("<%= _data_confirm %>");

    $(alertText).dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        title: "Note",
        width: 330,
        buttons: {
            "Continue with Application": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

.aspx.cs C#:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ClearIraDistributionConfirmation();
    }

    iraDistribution.TextChanged += iraDistribution_TextChanged;
}

void iraDistribution_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SessionFormData.ConfirmedIraDistribution == false
        && SessionFormData.IraDistribution.HasValue
        && SessionFormData.IraDistribution.Value > 0)
    {
        iraDistribution.Attributes[_data_confirm] =
            "<div>You must submit a copy of the first page of your 2014 federal tax return to verify the rollover amount.</div>";
        iraDistribution.Attributes[_aria_live] = "assertive";
        SessionFormData.ConfirmedIraDistribution = true;
    }
    else if (SessionFormData.ConfirmedIraDistribution)
    {
        ClearIraDistributionConfirmation();
    }
}


private void ClearIraDistributionConfirmation()
{
    if (SessionFormData.ConfirmedIraDistribution)
    {
        iraDistribution.Attributes.Clear();
    }
}
```

I've verified that at the end of the PostBack cycle, `iraDistribution` has no attributes set. As soon as my .aspx JS hits the very first line of JavaScript -- which is way before the JS I pasted here -- `iraDistribution` has its `data-confirm` attribute set.

What am I missing?

Comment: Should not be that hard to figure out if it rendered server side by looking at HTML or added in JavaScript (may need to debug code to see where it set so)... Look at source HTML and update question with information where it is set.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What you see in this code is the full cycle. The dialog div is created in C#. There's no server-side IDs involved here.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, see edit -- I clarified the question a bit.

Comment: It's not entirely clear as to where data-confirm is getting set since this isn't the entire page, is it only getting set within the text changed event?

Comment: Yep -- that's the only place. Edit: Gads -- I forgot enter submitted a comment. I've tried setting up events at other points in the post-back lifecycle and just can't get this to go away. I'm refactoring the way I store confirmations in the session right now to see if that's affected it.

Comment: Glad you found your problem. Now knowing the solution it is clear that your question could be more clear :) You've mentioned JavaScript which confused at least me (see my earlier comment) and C# code while showing all details did not highlight important pieces (adding the "data-confirm" attribute and removing it - named constants are nice, but in sample code it usually better to inline as many values as possible).

Comment: I'm going to try to be nice, because I get that my question was unclear. However, those kinds of comments are unhelpful. Copping a snarky, dismissive attitude while not even contributing anything meaningful is one of the reasons why Stack Overflow drives people away. I understand -- because I've been a member here for a while -- that obtuse questions like mine don't make it easy to do that, but your initial comment here was insulting, and your follow-up comment comes across as passive aggressive.

Comment: Figuring out my constants or asking questions about that -- which, it's worth noting, had absolutely nothing to do with the solution -- is one thing, but your retroactive justification for your own bad attitude is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is: The Page Life Cycle.

I made the mistake of trying to check for `TextBox` values in `OnInit` when they weren't yet available. `OnUnload` didn't work either because the values had already been rendered to output at that point.

I've fixed this bug by reordering the code above and moving it into the `OnLoadComplete` event. My code now looks like (well -- not quite like this, but it's abbreviated to remove code that interacts with the Session, functions I defined to improve readability, etc.):

```
protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoadComplete(e);

    if (SessionFormData.ConfirmedIraDistribution)
    {
        iraDistribution.Attributes.Clear();
    }
    else if (SessionFormData.ConfirmedIraDistribution == false
        && SessionFormData.IraDistribution.HasValue
        && SessionFormData.IraDistribution.Value > 0)
    {
        iraDistribution.Attributes[_data_confirm] =
            "<div>You must submit a copy of the first page of your 2014 federal tax return to verify the rollover amount.</div>";
        iraDistribution.Attributes[_aria_live] = "assertive";
        SessionFormData.ConfirmedIraDistribution = true;
    }
}
```

The moral of this story: The Page Life Cycle will eat your lunch.